# aws sdk validation error must be type object

Tags: php, validation, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to create a record set with the aws sdk  and I'm getting this validation error:

Validation errors: [ChangeBatch][Changes][0][Change][ResourceRecordSet][ResourceRecords][Value][ResourceRecord] must be of type object

My code looks like this:

```
$result = $r53->changeResourceRecordSets(array(
                'HostedZoneId' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                'ChangeBatch' => array(
                    'Changes' => array(
                        array(
                            'Action' => 'CREATE',
                            'ResourceRecordSet' => array(
                                'Name' => 'psion',
                                'Type' => 'CNAME',
                                'ResourceRecords' => array(
                                    'Value' => 'example.com'
                                ),
                            ),
                            'Change' => array(
                                'ResourceRecordSet' => array(
                                    'ResourceRecords' => array(
                                        'Value' => array(
                                            'ResourceRecord' => $aws->get('Route53'),
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ));
```

Any idea what the validation error means?

Answer (score 0):

> Validation errors: [ChangeBatch][Changes][0][Change][ResourceRecordSet][ResourceRecords][Value][ResourceRecord] must be of type object.

By type "object", it means an associative array. This is a validation message bubbling up from the Guzzle layer.

Here are the [API docs for `Route53Client::changeResourceRecordSets()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Route53.Route53Client.html#_changeResourceRecordSets), which shows an example of how the request should look when it is formatted correctly.

That whole array you have under the `'Change'` key is not correct at all.